# Ignoring control character in json response

Tags: java, json, control-characters

I have control character in my database table. I am retriving this data and sending the JSON response to client.  How we can ignore the control character at time of sending the response in Java.

Comment: Could you provide some example, what is your code, etc.

Comment: Why not just preprocess the value? E.g. `string.replaceAll("\\W", "")`